# How do I parallelize a `map` function on a pandas Series object?

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing

For example, I have a `Series` object whose values are the filenames of waveform dumps. Say, I want to take the average of each waveform.

Why do I want to parallelize this? These waveform dumps can only be read by proprietary software.  I need to call that program to do its analysis (it can output to `stdout`, so no problem with that).

In code, this is how it might look like:

```python
from subprocess import check_output

def get_average(filename_str):
    average = check_output(['proprietary_mean_calculator', filename_str])
    return float(average)

# waveform_dumps is a pandas Series object
waveform_averages = waveform_dumps.map(get_average)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably doesn't matter whether you are using pandas or not. What you are looking for is simple parallel execution.

Try [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)

```
from subprocess import check_output
import concurrent.futures
import pandas as pd

def get_average(filename_str):
    average = check_output(['proprietary_mean_calculator', filename_str])
    return float(average)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    waveform_averages = executor.map(get_average, waveform_dumps)

# to make the result a pd.Series, if desired:
waveform_averages = pd.Series(waveform_averages, index=waveform_dumps.index)
```

Comment: It appears I cannot run this from a script that I import from Jupyter Notebook (i.e. the code snippet is in an external script that I call from Notebook). Seems to be waiting to acquire a lock or something. If I run the code FROM the Notebook itself, it does fine. Anyway, thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Kit maybe it's better if you wrap the concurrent execution into a function, then call the function in the notebook, given the script is not to be run as main.

Comment: Great! Works like a charm.